# Can empty cells be entered into an array constant in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to enter an array constant in Excel that contains a properly empty (blank) cell.

If I just use two row or column separators after each other ({1,,3} or {1;;3}), I get an error message and the formula is not accepted.

Using an empty string ("") won't do, as the cell is not really empty (evaluates to TRUE by ISBLANK() or treated as blank in charts).

I have a vague memory that leaving array positions empty worked (at least with array constants within chart series) in Excel 2010, so perhaps this is only an issue for Excel 2013.

Comment: What are you doing with the array? Why won't 0 work?

Comment: I need it to be treated as a gap in a (line) chart. A zero value brings the line down to 0, and #N/A values are ignored (interpolated).

Comment: What if you use `NA()` instead of nothing

Comment: I am not able to plot NA() (or #N/A) values as blanks in charts, they are only interpolated.